# How can I mergen objects in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm having some trouble with my array below
I'd like to combine the objects that have the same timeslots.

I've tried looping through them and comparing all objects with eachothers timeslots. but (I think) because they are all seen as different instances it doesn't work.

**I'm not asking for a full solution**, but just some hints on how to compare these with eachother or how to approach this.

**My array**

```
[
    {
        "valid_days": ["0"],
        "timeslots": [
            {
                "from_time": "09:00",
                "to_time": "12:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "valid_days": ["1"],
        "timeslots": [
            {
                "from_time": "09:00",
                "to_time": "12:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "valid_days": ["2"],
        "timeslots": [
            {
                "from_time": "09:00",
                "to_time": "12:00"
            },
            {
                "from_time": "13:00",
                "to_time": "15:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "valid_days": ["3"],
        "timeslots": [
            {
                "from_time": "09:00",
                "to_time": "12:00"
            },
            {
                "from_time": "13:00",
                "to_time": "15:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Desired result**

```
[
    {
        "valid_days": ["0", "1"],
        "timeslots": [
            {
                "from_time": "09:00",
                "to_time": "12:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "valid_days": ["2", "3"],
        "timeslots": [
            {
                "from_time": "09:00",
                "to_time": "12:00"
            },
            {
                "from_time": "13:00",
                "to_time": "15:00"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+merge+object+arrays+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Also this will not be react specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally I found the solution for you.**
**can you check this once**

```js
const arr =[ { "valid_days": ["0"], "timeslots": [ {"from_time": "09:00","to_time": "12:00"}]},
  { "valid_days": ["1"],"timeslots": [{"from_time": "09:00","to_time": "12:00"}]},
  { "valid_days": ["2"],"timeslots": [{"from_time": "09:00","to_time": "12:00"},{"from_time": "13:00","to_time": "15:00"}]},
  { "valid_days": ["3"],"timeslots": [{"from_time": "09:00","to_time": "12:00"},{"from_time": "13:00","to_time": "15:00"}]}
]

const fun = (ar)=>{
 const output = ar.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const tmp = prev.find(e => JSON.stringify(e.timeslots)==JSON.stringify(curr.timeslots));
    if (tmp) {
      tmp.valid_days.push(...curr.valid_days);
    } else {
      prev.push({
        timeslots: curr.timeslots,
        valid_days: [...curr.valid_days]
      });
    }
    return prev;
  }, []);
  return output
}
console.log(fun(arr))
```

**can you check this once**

Comment: Wow, as I don't (yet) fully understand what everything does, it works flawlessly! Thanks

Comment: @Yorbjörn please could you  give a right mark for my answer that will be more helpfull for my answer. anyway thanks for appreciation

Comment: @jsN00b and @Yorbjörn please be aware that the above answer is not stable as you should not rely on `JSON.stringify` for deep comparisons. E.g. changing the order of your properties would break above code already.

`JSON.stringify({"from_time": "09:00","to_time": "12:00"}) !== JSON.stringify({"to_time": "12:00", "from_time": "09:00"})`

Comment: @Viktor Luft yeah I have noticed that too but how can we loosly compare objects. i have one solution we can use `Lodash` for this kind of things. lodash can handle easly with out deep check

Comment: @jsN00b If you need a generic deep comparison that works for all kind of data, there are several libraries that offers this capability. E.g. this one looks promising and is very lightweight: https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-object-diff

Answer (score 2):

As you only wanted to get some hints:

1. For looping you should get familiar with the classic loops in JS or with the very nice to use build-in array functions:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=de
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

2. For comparing in JS you should always use the "===" or "!==" instead of the "==" or "!=". Both kinds don't support to deeply compare objects. That means `{ foo: 'bar' } === { foo: 'bar' }` returns always `false`. So you have to compare yourself (maybe with a comparison function) the time-slot objects.

The rest should be straight-forward, I guess :)